# Аналог англійським "action" та "cut" у кінематографі

Tags: переклад, from-english

Голлівудські режисери на зйомках часто кричать у гучномовець слова *action* на початку зйомки сцени чи дубля, а також *cut*, коли зйомку завершено. Російські режисери (та українські російськомовні) кричать *мотор*.

Чи є усталені українські відповідники? Просто, на жаль, почути україномовного режисера - це наразі рідкість.

Comment: можна замість *мотор* кричати *камера*

Comment: @Yola, А є якісь письмові згадки про вживання такого вигуку?

Comment: Зазвичай англійською кажуть *Lights, Camera, Action*. Я просто переклав. В зйомках деяких типів фільмів ще використовують *Lights, Camera, Erection*:)

Comment: @Yola, отже, *action* - це не те саме, що *камера*.

Comment: Екшн, кат :) Спеціалістам ці слова відомі а поза контекстом action та cut і в англійскій мові мають інший сенс. Нехай Українські актери звикают до міжнародних стандартів, може з Голівудом співпрацювати стануть

Comment: @ArthurTarasov, аналогічне питання: чи є хоч одне джерело, яке підтверджує вживання слів *екшн* та *кат* в українському кіно? Можливо, стаття в Інтернеті чи відео зі зйомок?

Answer (score 3):

Буквальний переклад тут звичайно не підходить, мій варіант був би:

cut! == знято!

action! == поїхали! мотор! (або й просто) почали!

на громадському тв знайшовся ще варіант *пішов*
[(За лаштунками проекту ДЕІНДЕ «Vivienne Mort» 1:18)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNKwFHRUODs)

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! На цьому сайті ми заохочуємо науково-обґрунтовані відповіді. Як мінімум, необхідно надавати посилання на поважні джерела, які вказують, де, ким і як використовуються запропоновані варіанти. Власна думка може бути частиною відповіді, але не її основою. Відповіді, які не відповідають нашим критеріям якості, можуть бути «замінусовані» та/або видалені. Перегляньте також [faq].

Comment: А як щодо `дія!`, як у театрі?